# How do I calculate the degrees of freedom for this odds ratio?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I don't have a math background so I'm kinda improvising right now. I have a feeling the regular n-1 or n1+n2-2 rule doesn't apply here. These are the conditions.

> 522 people with diabetes
>
> 346 people without diabetes
>
> Mean allele frequency for a snp in the diabetes population: 0.415
>
> Mean allele frequency for a snp in the control population: 0.405

Using a confidence level of 95%, I get odds ratios of 0.89, 1.04, and 1.22 with 1.04 as the ratio for the means. Btw, the acceptable error rates for the two populations were slightly different - 0.04 for the diabetes population and 0.05 for the control population. I used the two confidence intervals to get the range of odds ratios. The expected proportions were the same.

I'm trying to test the mean odds ratio 1.04 against another previous value: 1.46. Am I only looking for one mean here? I assume that I should use a one-tailed test and a t-distribution. How do I get the degrees of freedom for this case?

Comment: Not familiar with the field. For each subject, is the observation 0 or 1? If YES, then google 'comparing two proportions'. With such large numbers the resulting statistic should be normal (so no DF needed). If NO, then please provide examples of the data; I suppose you;d need sample standard deviations for the diabetic and for the control group.

Comment: @eugheugh: You can't edit this in "the normal way" because you appear to be on a different account. If you sign in on your original account then you will be able to edit the post "normally".